# The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I have a UWP App running on Windows 10 / Xbox One that is working fine during runtime, but I can't debug it properly. I'm getting "The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time." in all properties of native components. I can see normally the values on my Objects or components, but the native ones no.

Here is when I try to see the content of a StackPanel:

[image: Here is when I try to see the content of a StackPanel]

Here is when I try to see the content of my Object:

[image: Here is when I try to see the content of my Object]

It worked fine using the VS 2017, now the same code on VS 2019 are giving this problem. I have a fresh installation in a new machine, all the dependencies are installed also.

Is really hard to debug errors in this way, is remember me when I worked developing for MS DOS :)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Release or debug?

Comment: I'm trying in Debug AnyCPU.